# how to replace place marker with last click?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**JS**

```
var map;

function initialize()
{
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(13.001294, 77.661736);
    var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:15,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
  });
  document.getElementById("latt").innerHTML = location.lat();
  document.getElementById("long").innerHTML = location.lng();

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
<p id="latt"></p>
<p id="long"></p>
```

Here when we click on map more than one, there are number of place marker will appear. I want only one placemarker that last clicked place. How to fix that problem..? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the marker and keep moving it instead:

```
var marker;

function placeMarker(location) {
  if (!marker) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
    });
  } else {
    marker.setPosition(location);
  }
  document.getElementById("latt").innerHTML = location.lat();
  document.getElementById("long").innerHTML = location.lng();
}
```

Edit: latitude doesn't have a double t so id would make more sense as "lat". I can assure you that if you misspell it, your colleagues will get annoyed at having to remember that you can't spell it properly :)

Comment: *your colleagues will get annoyed at having to remember that you can't spell it properly* lol but that's so true!

Comment: @MrUpsidown - Personal experience... I named a db column lattitude. Whoops :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove your marker before adding a new one.

```
var map;
var marker;

function initialize() {

    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(13.001294, 77.661736);
    var mapProp = {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}

function placeMarker(location) {

    // Remove last marker
    marker.setMap(null);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map,
    });

    document.getElementById("latt").innerHTML = location.lat();
    document.getElementById("long").innerHTML = location.lng();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```